# Как передать значения переменных из .py в проект на C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, python, winforms

Такая ситуация:

Есть python файл, который обращается к API и получает значения. В итоге, значения обрабатываются и заносятся в 3 переменные (minValue, avgValue, maxValue). К примеру- minValue = 21.5 , avgValue = 22.3 , maxValue = 23.8

Сам скрипт .py запускается при клике на кнопку Windows Forms.

После этого я хочу вывести в MessageBox'e значения этих трех переменных.

Как можно реализовать?

Может использовать так называемого "посредника"? Допустим, занести данные этих переменных в .txt и оттуда их вытянуть уже на C# и отобразить в MessageBox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180694/passing-data-between-python-and-c-sharp-without-writing-a-file